# How to filter by date using OData query options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, odata

I have a Grid of a Cards which is generated when view is loaded.
By default I have:

```
<QueryFilter>OrderId ne 0L</QueryFilter>
<Ordering>Id asc</Ordering>
```

It means that Cards in my grid will be sorted by its Id's and also Card will be in grid only if `OrderId` is not 0 (`$filter=OrderId ne 0L`).

My Card class also contains datetime `DateEx` (expiration date).
I need to extend my filter and add to `OrderId ne 0L` something which will show Card in grid only if `DateEx` is `null` OR if it is more or equal to current real datetime.

How this kind of `$filter` supposed to look?

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this:

```
$filter=OrderId ne 0L and DateEx eq null & $orderby=Id asc
```